# How to pass prop from parent component in html to component vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I made this using `vue-cli`. I have a component called `InputField`, and  I render and mount the component to `#app`. I know that it will inject the component to the app, but how can I get the "default" value in `index.html` and access it in `InputField.vue`? I've tried to add `props: "default"` but the default value is undefined.

The idea is to get the default value from the component in `html` and save it to `values` in data when component is mounted.

I added the following ...

... to my `html` but seems like it wont work in `vue-cli`?

Also in my template I added `default="def"` like this:

```
<input default="def" v-model="values" name="my-input" />
```

But when I refer to `"default"` in `js` it is undefined.

**InputField.vue**

```
<template>
<div >
    <input default="def" v-model="valuess" name="my-input" />
    
<input
      v-model="message"
      type="text">
      <h2 class="message">{{ message }}</h2>

</div>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports={
        name:'InputField',
        props:["default"],
        mounted(){

             console.log(this.default);
               this.valuess=this.default;
        },
        updated(){
            if(this.valuess===this.default){
                return this.$emit('dirty-field',false);
            }
            this.$emit('dirty-field',true);
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                valuess: '',
                message:'heelo',
               
            }
        
    }
    }
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="app">
    <InputField default="My default text"></InputField>
   
    </div>
```

**main.js**

```
new Vue({

render: h => h(InputField),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: You can't do what you try to do. `<InputField` in index isn't related to component hierarchy that you have inside the app. It's just discarded on app init. If you need to pass initial data, pass it through `window` or `data` attributes on known element (likely `<div id="app">`)

Comment: @EstusFlask do you mean i have to pass data in InputField.vue? i added `<input default="def" v-model="valuess" name="my-input" />` but default still undefined? i should use v-bind?

Comment: You need to pass default data to your app from the outside. Again, with `window` or else. Not through InputField props. `input` doesn't have `default` attribute, so `<input default="def"` isn't supposed to do anything.

Comment: @EstusFlask thankyou how can i pass the default attribute through data? is it only possible to inject component to #app in vue cli?

Comment: I meant not Vue `data` but data attribute exactly, `<div id="app" data-input-default="...">`, and read it from `appEl.dataset`

Comment: @EstusFlask ok should i add '<div id="app" data-input-default="...">' in the inputfield component? where should i put the dataset? inside the new Vue?

Comment: The idea is to define data from outside the app (index file) and read it from inside the app (input component). Just define a global variable in body `<script>`, this is really simple solution that is commonly used in such situations.

Comment: @EstusFlask '<div id="app" data-input-default="...">' ok so i made default variable in div in index file? how can i read it from component without prop?

Comment: See above, `appEl.dataset` . You can get `appEl` with querySelector or else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass default props like this with `:default`:

```
<InputField :default="My default text"></InputField>
```

Comment: do you mean v-bind?

Comment: I tried to add `v-bind:defaults="this.default"` but still get undefined

Comment: v-bind:defaults or v-bind:default ??

Comment: A binding results in `My default text` being treated as JS expression, which isn't a valid one.